# Initializing custom output stream before main

Tags: c, stdout, extern

Say I want to write an API (for C/Linux) that offers a customized output stream, like `stdout` but mine should be called `not_stdout`. So I could demand that people using my API always begin their main program by calling a function `init_the_stream()` that initializes `extern FILE* not_stdout`.

But what I'd really like is for my stream to be initialized prior to `main()`, so that it works just like `stdout`.

I would guess that this is somewhat hard to do in a portable way, since the C standard wants prior-to-main initialized variables to be constants or string literals, and that `stdout` gets special compiler treatment. But I'm not sure, so I want to ask:

Is it possible to write a C library such that stuff like `extern FILE* not_stdout` is initialized before the first line of `main()` whenever the library is included?

Comment: As the standard defined `main` as the starting point of the language, there apparently is no standard way. It depends on your platform. But you should be careful with such automatisms. Only use them if the regular way has major impact on the code. (which I don't see for your own library).

Comment: You can hide `main()` into your library and have the user write a `myMain` that is called from there. This is how Microsoft's `WinMain()` came into being.

Answer (score 1):

On gcc and clang, you can use [`__attribute__((constructor))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes) (not standard C).

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
__attribute__((constructor))
static void not_stdout__init(void)
{
   puts("initializing not_stdout");
}
int main()
{
    puts("main");
}
```

It works well with dynamically linked (.so) or loaded (dlopen) ELF libraries – if a library provides such hooks, they will get invoked when the library gets linked in.

If you want to be portable, you could leave the initializer externally visible (no `static`) and conditionally add the constructor attribute only if it's supported. That way, your users could invoke the initializer from main manually if no mechanism exists to make their platform do it for them.

Comment: This is perfect, and so idiomatically appropriate in its hackiness!

Comment: You use `stdout` in your constructor; are there any guarantees that `stdout` has been initialized before your constructor is called? In general, is there any guarantee of sequencing of constructors like this? What if a hypothetical `stdlog` and `not_stdout` should be initialized, but `stdlog` depends on `not_stdout` being initialized first? Do you have to make sure that the constructor is idempotent, so if it should only be used once, it does no harm on a second invocation?  Should it call pre-requisite constructors (so the hypothetical `stdlog` constructor calls the `not_stdout` constructor)?

Comment: You can sequence constructors by assigning priority to the call so that's not a problem. Also, clearly he's using the stdout call as a placeholder. Also you make sure the constructor does not get called twice by wrapping the header in #IFDEFs. This is standard stuff. I downvote your downvote.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It's possible to specify a numerical priority 101 to 2^16-1 after constructor, in parentheses. The lesser the number the higher the priority. Without the priority (or for a group of ctors with the same priority), ctors within a translation unit are run in order.  It's all in gcc docs (which I suppose you already know). IDK about stdio being guaranteed to be available in the constructors, but the example works, and I don't suppose many actual initializers will want to use stdio.

Comment: @embedded_crysis: I don't know whose down-vote you're referring to, and neither do you — but I can tell you it was not mine. I don't down-vote very often — you can look at my stats to see that.  Accusing people of DV-ing is not constructive.

Comment: @embedded_crysis The constructors should be put inside implementation files (*.c), not headers.